# How magento uses modified code in googles analytics for tracking

Tags: magento, google-analytics

I saw many tutorials that teaches just getting the number in google analytics and putting it in magento, but i want to change the default code in  analytics. My doubt is, only the number provided by analytics will be sufficient for magento sees my changes in the tracking code or i need to put the code like in a normal site?
Is there a good manual for coding in analytics for e-commerce beyond the guidelines offered by google for developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the Google Analytics account number into Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Google API will be sufficient enough. It will track your ecommerce sales data (this code is rendered on the success page - success.phtml) as well as placing the general tracking code throughout the site.

Comment: Yes, but this initial code track every page in my store or need to edit this?